# call to undefined function mssql_connect() linux hosting

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, web-hosting

I am using `Godaddy Deluxe Web Hosting` with `Linux OS`. `PHP` version is `5.3`.

I got this error :

```
    Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() 
in ... index.php on line ...
```

What I need then :

1. I have created `php5.ini` file
2. I have added these options :

   extension_dir = ./

   extension=php_mssql.dll
3. I have downloaded php_mssql.dll file and added it to root dir
4. I have reloaded hosting.
5. I saw no changes...

Is it possible to work with mssql with php5.3 on Linux web hosting?

Comment: Since this is Linux hosting, you will be needing something other than a .dll.  You'll need to contact your host support to find out if this will be possible.

Comment: Typically it also requires the FreeTDS client libraries, and would of course require your MS SQL server to be allowing inbound tcp connections on the public IP of your shared host (which is kind of scary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

install On linux

```
apt-get install php5-sybase
```

Check service On

```
php -m | grep mssql
```

you can see mssql on service

Answer (score 1):

The parts

> with Linux OS

and

> extension=php_mssql.dll

bite each other IMHO. On linux, you load .so files and not .dll files. I'd suggest to talk to GoDaddy instead.

Answer (score 0):

MS = Microsoft, so no not on Linux by default, and probably very hard to get it on there and usable (never tried myself).  If you are using GoDaddy Hosting, they should have MySQL which is essentially the same set up (DBs, tables, columns, rows, SQL, etc).  Look into MySQL on the PHP Docs site: [MySQL Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php).  You may have to log into your hosting backend and add a database and user manually before you can connect to it.

Comment: You _can_ easily run php_mssql on Linux, just not with many shared-hosting setups.

Comment: @Tim Withers Thanks for the informations, but I am already familiar to mysql. In my case I have third party application which uses mssql and I want to be able to manage it from the site.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux hosting with Go Daddy you are not able to setup a MSSQL database which indicates you are tying to connect to a third party MSSQL database.  Go Daddy does not allow you to connect to third party databases.  This is not going to be possible.